# Very short timer in MIPS

Tags: c, timer, io, mips32

I am quite new to low-level programming and am struggling with an assignment. I'm trying to control a [LED strip](https://www.electrokit.com/produkt/led-slinga-neopixel-rgbw-1m/) with my [MIPS microcontroller](https://digilent.com/reference/microprocessor/uno32/start?redirect=1). I am not allowed to use any IDE and have to code everything by myself. According to the documentation, in order to send a 1 to the LED strip, I have to set the chosen pin up for .6us (+- .15us) and then down for the same duration. To send a 0, it is .3 us up and then .9 us down.
My processor runs at 80MHz. I therefore computed the timer period 80e6 * 0.3e-6 = 24 corresponding to .3 us. I wrote the following function:

```
/* wait for 0.<timer> microseconds */
void wait(int timer) {
   int i;
   switch(timer){
      case 3:
         T2CONSET = 0x8000; // start
         while (1) {
            if (IFS(0) & 0x100) { // interrupt flag raised for timer 2
               T2CONCLR = 0x8000; // stop T2
               IFSCLR(0) = 0x100; // reset interrupt flag atomically
               break;
            }
         }
         break;
      case 6:
         for (i=0; i<2;i++) {
            T2CONSET = 0x8000; // start T2
            while (1) {
               if (IFS(0) & 0x100) { // interrupt flag raised
                  T2CONCLR = 0x8000; // stop T2
                  IFSCLR(0) = 0x100; // reset flag atomically
                  break;
               }
            }
         }
         break;
      case 9:
         for (i=0; i<3;i++) {
            T2CONSET = 0x8000; // start T2
            while (1) {
               if (IFS(0) & 0x100) { // interrupt flag raised
                  T2CONCLR = 0x8000; // stop
                  IFSCLR(0) = 0x100; // reset flag atomically
                  break;
               }
            }
         }
         break;
      default:
         break;
   }
}
```

I call this function from the following, that takes as input the 32-bit code for controlling the LEDs:

```
/* Send 32-bit data to the LED strip. chosen pin is D8
 * number of bits per color, in that order 0-7:R 0-7:G 0-7:B 0-7:W
 */
void send2LED(long int data){
   int i;
   char isOne;
   for (i=0; i<32; i++){
      isOne = data & 0x80000000; // filter first bit of data
      if (isOne) {
         PORTDSET = 0x100; // set PORTD(8) up
         wait(6);
         PORTDCLR = 0x100; // set PORTD(8) down
         wait(6);
      } else {
         PORTDSET = 0x100; // pin up
         wait(3);
         PORTDCLR = 0x100; // pin down
         wait(9);
      }
      data = data << 1;
   }
}
```

However, when I connect an oscilloscope to the output pin, I observe that the desired periods are off by a factor around 10000. Changing the period found reduce this enough for my LED strip to work.

Is there a basic principle that I have missed? I have tried to make the functions as straight forward as possible, but do I still have too much overhead? Any help is much welcome <3

Comment: Start by replacing all "magic numbers" with meaningful names. As it stands, you force the reader of your code to sit with their nose buried in the manual while reading the code. [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290)

Comment: As for how to write this proper using hardware timers and cyclic interrupts, well that's another story entirely. Use PWM hardware if available. If you intend to generate a PWM for a LED then those times don't make sense at all, you should run at much lower frequencies or you might as well stay active high/active low.

Comment: I just did this myself a little bit ago on a pic24.  The pic24 has an SPI peripheral that I was able to use to send the correct wave form.  That is probably the way to go if you have an SPI peripheral.  My original implementation bit banged it (what you are doing).  It worked, but it was clunky getting it right.  You don't want to use `delay`/`wait` for that.  They have their own overhead and the timing was too tight.  I had to use `nop`s (AKA no-operation) to get the timing right.

Comment: @Jason so basically chaining up 24 ```nop```s to cover the desired timer period of .3 us? And not use a timer?

Comment: If you base your SPI transmission on bit periods of 0.3µs, you can use 4 bits per LED: 1000 for "off" and 1100 for "on".

Comment: @lukasgamard More of a guess and check against the scope.  @busybee I did almost exactly that.  My LED strip had different timing so I used `1100` and `1110`

Comment: @thebusybee do you do this by setting the Baud Rate? Because I only have 9 BRG bits on my machine, and a bit period of .3 us is equivalent to 3.33e6 bits/sec, which would require more than 20 bits in base 2. Please correct me if I have misunderstood something.